# Issue with telerik RadGrid insert button

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

Currently I have a page with radgrid and a few other asp.net textboxes with requiredfield validators.
Anyway the issue is that I can't insert into the radgrid when the other textboxes are not filled in (due to the validators). Is there anyway to allow the user to enter data into the radgrid without forcing them to entering stuff into the textboxes first. Please tell me if I need to provide code samples, etc.

Many thanks.

Comment: Actually dont worry about this anymore - I just used validationgroups to overcome this issue. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code snippet.

I guess that you are used inline edit mode / Used inbuilt EditCommandColumn.

Note : If you are used ButtonType is different then standarad button then used LinkButton / ImageButton In place of Button in Below Code snippet.

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.IsInEditMode)
    {
        if (e.Item is GridDataInsertItem)
        {
            // Insert
            GridEditableItem editItem = (GridEditableItem)e.Item;
            Button InsertButton = (Button)editItem.FindControl("PerformInsertButton");
            InsertButton.CausesValidation = false; 
            //or
            InsertButton.ValidationGroup = "test";

        }
        else
        {
            // Update
            GridEditableItem editItem = (GridEditableItem)e.Item;
            Button updateButton = (Button)editItem.FindControl("UpdateButton");
            updateButton.CausesValidation = false;
            //or
            updateButton.ValidationGroup = "test";

        }
    }
```